# 2 time periods in one report SQL Reportbuilder 2012 3.0

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

[image: 2 periods in one report]

I would like to see a report in Microsoft SQL Reportbuilder 3.0 2012 of both periods shown in the picture. I made a query that will show me the red period but I can't seem to get the black period together with the red period in one report. They need to be 2 different columns next to each other.
The purpose of this report is to show all bookings on a certain project from start till today and also to see them for a certain month specifically. 
Is there even a way to do this or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would share the answer. This is the code I used to fix my problem.

```
 SELECT 
    tblReg.PurchaseOrderId,
    tblReg.Reference AS PO, 
    SUM(HoursBefore) AS HoursBefore, 
    SUM(HoursBefore)/8 AS DaysBefore, 
    SUM(HoursBetween) AS HoursBetween, 
    SUM(HoursBetween)/8 AS DaysBetween, 
    SUM(HoursAfter) AS HoursAfter, 
    SUM(HoursAfter)/8 AS DaysAfter, 
    MIN(BudgetDays) AS BudgetDays
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        po.PurchaseOrderId,
        po.Reference,
        BudgetDays,
        CASE 
            WHEN reg.RegistrationDate < @StartDate THEN DurationHours
            ELSE 0
        END AS HoursBefore,
        CASE 
            WHEN reg.RegistrationDate >= @StartDate AND reg.RegistrationDate <= @EndDate THEN DurationHours
            ELSE 0
        END AS HoursBetween,
        CASE 
            WHEN reg.RegistrationDate > @EndDate THEN DurationHours
            ELSE 0
        END AS HoursAfter
    FROM Registration reg
    INNER JOIN PurchaseOrder po ON reg.PurchaseOrderId = po.PurchaseOrderId
    WHERE po.statuscid = 1 AND reg.IsBillable = 1 AND SetNonBillable = 0 --AND reg.RegistrationDate >= @StartDate AND reg.RegistrationDate <= @EndDate
)tblReg
GROUP BY tblReg.PurchaseOrderId, tblReg.Reference
ORDER BY tblReg.Reference;
```